# Can I change the bootstrap popover title style dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

this seems to be something asked many many times, but I cannot get it to work in my situation.

I have a table which has td elements with a background-color set.

When I setup the popover (which has a title and content image) I would like to set the title to have the same background-color as the td element.

I'm using jquery, and bootstratp 3.3.7 and have the following code so far (which works fine)

...

```
$('td').hover(function(){
                // mousein
                $(this).popover({
                        animation: true,
                        container: 'body',
                        content : $(this).attr("popover-content"),
                        title : $(this).attr("popover-title"),
                        placement : "right",
                        html : "true",
                        trigger : "manual",
                });
                $(".popover-title").css('background-color',$(this).css('background-colo
r')+' !important');
                $(this).popover('show');
        },function(){
                // mouseout
                $(this).popover('hide');
        });
```

...

The bit that doesn't work is the change to the css on class popover-title.

I must be missing something important so would appreciate some help?

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 0):

As per [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/css/):

> **Note:** `.css()` ignores `!important` declarations. So, the statement `$( "p" ).css( "color", "red !important" )` does not turn the color of all paragraphs in the page to red. It's strongly advised to use classes instead; otherwise use a jQuery plugin.

So, what you can do, is apply one of many classes which, in your CSS, are styled individually, using `!important`. But, chances are you don't need `!important` at all. All you need is to override the specificity of the already applying style.

Comment: OK understood. If I remove it as suggested still no change. I didn't realise that jquery ignores it but it was one of many attempts based on extensive research of similar questions.

Comment: Without a *runnable* [mcve] I cannot help you, as I don't know what I have to override and I have no means of testing any potential solution. Reproduce your problem in a question snippet or on your snippet website of choice and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone tripping up over this particular issue this is how I solved it.

1) by adding a function linked to the popover show event (found on a related article here in SO!) eg

```
<!-- bootstrap tooltip plugin -->
$('td').hover(function(){
        // mousein
        $(this).popover({
                animation: true,
                container: 'body',
                content : $(this).attr("popover-content"),
                title : $(this).attr("popover-title"),
                placement : "right",
                html : "true",
                trigger : "manual",
        }).on("show.bs.popover", function(){
                if ($(this).attr("popover-content")) {
                        $(this).data("bs.popover").tip().css('background-color',$(this).css('background-color'));
                } else {
                        $(this).data("bs.popover").tip().css('background-color','#107a9d');
                }
        });
        $(this).popover('show');
},function(){
        // mouseout
        $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

2. By making the background-color "inherit" what is (presumably) the tip() css.